# SQL Server Dynamic Resetting Running Balance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My current issue is that I have a running balance, where one value falls below another the running balance needs to reset. But not only reset, but also use a another value as its starting value and start the balance again.

Below is the table with data in it:

```
+-------------+--------+---------------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------+
| Tran_DateSK | Amount | Running_AccountFees | Overlimit_Balance | Restart_Calc | Actual_Calc |
+-------------+--------+---------------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------+
|    20200217 |     39 |                  39 |           3867.76 |            0 |          39 |
|    20200217 |     50 |                  89 |           3867.76 |            0 |          89 |
|    20200316 |     39 |                 128 |           4735.52 |            0 |         128 |
|    20200316 |     50 |                 178 |           4735.52 |            0 |         178 |
|    20200324 |     50 |                 228 |           2685.52 |            0 |         228 |
|    20200330 |     50 |                 278 |             49.52 |            1 |       49.52 |
|    20200415 |     39 |                 317 |             49.52 |            1 |       49.52 |
|    20200515 |     39 |                 356 |           3917.28 |            0 |       88.52 |
|    20200515 |     50 |                 406 |           3917.28 |            0 |      138.52 |
|    20200519 |     50 |                 456 |           3467.28 |            0 |      188.52 |
|    20200604 |     50 |                 506 |           3017.28 |            0 |      238.52 |
|    20200609 |     50 |                 556 |           2167.28 |            0 |      288.52 |
|    20200611 |     50 |                 606 |             49.28 |            1 |       49.28 |
|    20200615 |     39 |                 645 |           3917.04 |            0 |       88.28 |
|    20200615 |     50 |                 695 |           3917.04 |            0 |      138.28 |
|    20200616 |     50 |                 745 |           3017.04 |            0 |      188.28 |
|    20200616 |     50 |                 795 |           3017.04 |            0 |      238.28 |
|    20200619 |     50 |                 845 |           2567.04 |            0 |      288.28 |
|    20200624 |     50 |                 895 |             47.04 |            1 |       47.04 |
|    20200715 |     39 |                 934 |             47.04 |            1 |       47.04 |
+-------------+--------+---------------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Actual Calc is the desired outcome and Running account fees is the issue.

Running account fees is the running balance of **"Amount"** and **overlimit_balance** is the test. We need to see that the **running_accountfees** isn't greater than **over limit**,

If it is, take overlimits value and start calculating again by adding amount on again.

My query that produced this:

```
    SELECT 
    [Transaction].ReportDateSK                              AS 'Tran_DateSK'
    ,[Transaction].AmountChange/100.00                      AS 'Amount'
    ,SUM([Transaction].AmountChange/100.00) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY [Transaction].AccountSK
        ORDER BY [Transaction].ReportDateSK
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 0 PRECEDING)   AS 'Running_AccountFees'
    ,[Summary].Overlimit_Balance                            AS 'Overlimit_Balance'
    ,CASE 
        WHEN SUM([Transaction].AmountChange/100.00) 
                OVER (PARTITION BY [Transaction].AccountSK
                ORDER BY [Transaction].ReportDateSK
                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 0 PRECEDING) > [Summary].Overlimit_Balance
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END                                                     AS 'Restart_Calc'
    ,''                                                     AS 'Actual_Calc'
FROM  
    Fact.[Transaction] [Transaction]
    INNER JOIN Fact.AccountSummary [Summary] ON [Summary].DateSK = [Transaction].ReportDateSK
        AND [Summary].AccountSK = [Transaction].AccountSK
        AND [Summary].[Current] = 1
WHERE IsFeeTransaction = 1
    AND [Transaction].AccountSK = 725
    AND [Transaction].ReportDateSK BETWEEN 20200217 AND 20200730
```

Comment: My guess is that you need to use ["Gaps and Islands"](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/) approach. To give you a working solution I would need a DDL script and/or [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: As Alex said, please add your source data to go with your current script and desired output.  It is rather hard to help without knowing your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised that the data in your question *is* essentially the source data and have been able to come up with the below.  It isn't exactly pretty but it provides the correct output.  Explanations on how it works are in the comments:

```
declare @t table(Tran_DateSK int, Amount decimal(10,2), Running_AccountFees int, Overlimit_Balance decimal(10,2), Restart_Calc bit, Actual_Calc decimal(10,2));
insert into @t values(20200217,39,39,3867.76,0,39),(20200217,50,89,3867.76,0,89),(20200316,39,128,4735.52,0,128),(20200316,50,178,4735.52,0,178),(20200324,50,228,2685.52,0,228),(20200330,50,278,49.52,1,49.52),(20200415,39,317,49.52,1,49.52),(20200515,39,356,3917.28,0,88.52),(20200515,50,406,3917.28,0,138.52),(20200519,50,456,3467.28,0,188.52),(20200604,50,506,3017.28,0,238.52),(20200609,50,556,2167.28,0,288.52),(20200611,50,606,49.28,1,49.28),(20200615,39,645,3917.04,0,88.28),(20200615,50,695,3917.04,0,138.28),(20200616,50,745,3017.04,0,188.28),(20200616,50,795,3017.04,0,238.28),(20200619,50,845,2567.04,0,288.28),(20200624,50,895,47.04,1,47.04),(20200715,39,934,47.04,1,47.04);

with t as
(
    select Tran_DateSK
          ,Amount
          -- Check if the Running_AccountFees are over the Overlimit_Balance
          ,case when sum(Amount) over (order by Tran_DateSK,Amount,Overlimit_Balance rows unbounded preceding) > Overlimit_Balance
                        -- If so, check if the Running_AccountFees in the previous row were also over the Overlimit_Balance
                  then case when (sum(Amount) over (order by Tran_DateSK,Amount,Overlimit_Balance rows unbounded preceding) - Amount) > lag(Overlimit_Balance,1,0) over (order by Tran_DateSK,Amount,Overlimit_Balance)
                            then 0      -- and in those instances this means multiple Restart_Calcs in a row, so set the Amount to zero as we don't want to increase the fees when calculating the Actual_Calc
                            else Amount
                            end
              else Amount
              end as Amount_Adj

          ,sum(Amount) over (order by Tran_DateSK,Amount,Overlimit_Balance rows unbounded preceding) as Running_AccountFees
          
          ,lag(Overlimit_Balance,1,0) over (order by Tran_DateSK,Amount,Overlimit_Balance) as Prev_Overlimit_Balance
          
          ,Overlimit_Balance

          ,case when sum(Amount) over (order by Tran_DateSK,Amount,Overlimit_Balance rows unbounded preceding) > Overlimit_Balance
                then 1
                else 0
                end as Restart_Calc
    from @t
)
,b as
(
    select *
          ,case when Running_AccountFees > Overlimit_Balance    -- If this row is the first in a possible series of balance resets
                    and sum(Amount_Adj) over (order by Tran_DateSK,Amount,Overlimit_Balance rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) <= Prev_Overlimit_Balance
                then Overlimit_Balance      -- Take the Overlimit_Balance and subtract the *Adjusted* Running_AccountFees
                     - sum(Amount_Adj) over (order by Tran_DateSK,Amount,Overlimit_Balance rows  between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
                     - Amount_Adj
                else 0
                end as Reset_Bal
    from t
)
select Tran_DateSK
      ,Amount
      ,Running_AccountFees
      ,Overlimit_Balance
      ,Restart_Calc
      -- For each *Adjusted* Running_AccountFees, apply the most negative Reset_Bal value, as this will contain the entire amount that needs to be reset from the current *Adjusted* Running_AccountFees to get the correct Balance_Calc
      ,sum(Amount_Adj) over (order by Tran_DateSK,Amount,Overlimit_Balance rows unbounded preceding)
        + min(Reset_Bal) over (order by Tran_DateSK,Amount,Overlimit_Balance rows unbounded preceding)
        as Balance_Calc
from b
order by Tran_DateSK;
```

### Output

```
+-------------+--------+---------------------+-------------------+--------------+--------------+
| Tran_DateSK | Amount | Running_AccountFees | Overlimit_Balance | Restart_Calc | Balance_Calc |
+-------------+--------+---------------------+-------------------+--------------+--------------+
|    20200217 |  39.00 |               39.00 |           3867.76 |            0 |        39.00 |
|    20200217 |  50.00 |               89.00 |           3867.76 |            0 |        89.00 |
|    20200316 |  39.00 |              128.00 |           4735.52 |            0 |       128.00 |
|    20200316 |  50.00 |              178.00 |           4735.52 |            0 |       178.00 |
|    20200324 |  50.00 |              228.00 |           2685.52 |            0 |       228.00 |
|    20200330 |  50.00 |              278.00 |             49.52 |            1 |        49.52 |
|    20200415 |  39.00 |              317.00 |             49.52 |            1 |        49.52 |
|    20200515 |  39.00 |              356.00 |           3917.28 |            0 |        88.52 |
|    20200515 |  50.00 |              406.00 |           3917.28 |            0 |       138.52 |
|    20200519 |  50.00 |              456.00 |           3467.28 |            0 |       188.52 |
|    20200604 |  50.00 |              506.00 |           3017.28 |            0 |       238.52 |
|    20200609 |  50.00 |              556.00 |           2167.28 |            0 |       288.52 |
|    20200611 |  50.00 |              606.00 |             49.28 |            1 |        49.28 |
|    20200615 |  39.00 |              645.00 |           3917.04 |            0 |        88.28 |
|    20200615 |  50.00 |              695.00 |           3917.04 |            0 |       138.28 |
|    20200616 |  50.00 |              745.00 |           3017.04 |            0 |       188.28 |
|    20200616 |  50.00 |              795.00 |           3017.04 |            0 |       238.28 |
|    20200619 |  50.00 |              845.00 |           2567.04 |            0 |       288.28 |
|    20200624 |  50.00 |              895.00 |             47.04 |            1 |        47.04 |
|    20200715 |  39.00 |              934.00 |             47.04 |            1 |        47.04 |
+-------------+--------+---------------------+-------------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Nice answer, I put a Cursor loop in and kept a variable running balance. I tested IO/Time against yours, yours is much more performant.

Comment: No worries.  As a general rule, you should really try to not ever use a cursor anymore.  The number of actual use cases is miniscule.